# callback() produces a snytax error. Object not a function

Tags: javascript, callback

```
    var ajax = function(url,callback) {

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    if(window.ActiveXObject) {
        var xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    this.xml = xml;
    alert(xml);
    xml.onreadystatechange = function(callback) {
    callback = callback();
            if(xml.readyState == 4 && xml.status == 200) {
            alert(xml);

            }       
    }
    xml.open('GET',url,true);
    xml.send(null);

}

ajax('/server/eChck.php?email=email@yahoo.com',function(){
    alert(xml);
});
```

the callback() wont work. Produces syntax error. can any explain to me how I would code this so I could put my callback() inside of the parameter?

Thanks, 
Jon W

Comment: "Object is not a function" is a *runtime* error, not a syntax error. It means that the "callback" parameter is not a function.

Comment: You don't want to give your `onreadystatechange` callback a `callback` parameter (it will be called with an event), you want to use the `callback` variable that is a parameter to your `ajax` function

Comment: @Pointy more precisely it's a TypeError, not that that's the big deal here - OP doesn't know the syntax of JavaScript and is pretty much copy pasting code.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum well then this is a "teachable moment" :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DHz6h/1/

Answer (score 1):

There are two mistakes here:

```
xml.onreadystatechange = function(callback) {
callback = callback();
        if(xml.readyState == 4 && xml.status == 200) {
        alert(xml);

        }       
}
```

First, you're creating the ready state change handler as a function that takes a parameter, which isn't incorrect but you've named that parameter "callback". That means that inside the state change handler, "callback" refers to that parameter, not to the "callback" passed in to the outer function.

Second, by assigning to "callback" the result of *calling* the callback function, you'll overwrite the value each time the event handler is called.

I think you want something like this:

```
xml.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xml.readyState == 4 && xml.status == 200) {
          callback();
        }       
}
```

*edit* — In addition to those changes, you should declare the "xml" variable in your "ajax" function:

```
var ajax = function(url,callback) {
    var xml;
```

And take out this line:

```
    this.xml = xml; // take this out
```

Comment: That still produces a syntax error. Object is not a function.

Comment: @JonW again, that's not a syntax error. If you're really calling that "ajax" function as it says in your code, and you've really changed the code as in my example above, then you won't get that error.

Comment: I change all of what you said. Same problem still. Object is not function. it refering to callback() when I try and run it as a function.

Comment: @JonW Can you update your question and add the new code?

Comment: @JonW look at this version in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DHz6h/1/) that intrepid user adeneo made for you

Comment: excellent! Thanks! That exactly what I was trying to pull off. Now I should be able to modify it from here if I choose to retrieve my data and handle it with XML. Thanks again!